# Modifying WordPress's "post-new.php" File for Custom Blog Entries

Tags: php, wordpress, drupal, content-management-system

Has anyone ever modified the "post-new.php" file in their WordPress installation?

I want to modify the look of this page to include pieces that I standardly include in my blog posts, and I just don't know if it is do-able/easy/worth my time.

Should I just find another CMS that allows more modifcation like Drupal?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No reason to modify the core files - you can add stuff via plugins. See, for example, [the more fields plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/more-fields/) - it adds to the new/edit post form without breaking your ability to upgrade the core installation.

Drupal's great, but if you're focusing on blogging you may get better results tweaking WP via plugins. I use WordPress for blog sites, and Drupal for most others.